# Importing my .ovpn file into my DDWRT router. Having issues on matching up parameters

Tags: openvpn, dd-wrt

I just setup ovpn on my ubuntu server and I generated a .ovpn file as seen below. It works on my desktop using the openVPN client using the file. Now I want to import this into my DDWRT router, but I have to manually pick the parameters as seen below.

I'm stuck as to what I need to put in the DDWRT setting according to my .ovpn file.

As for the **tls-cipher**, I can't find the setting in DDWRT for **TLS-ECDHE-ECDSA-WITH-AES-128-GCM-SHA256**. I'm not sure what to pick or do I need to change this on my server side?

Also what do I pick for LZO compression?

And I'm not sure if my keys are going to the correct place as seen below.

What else could I be missing here?

[image]

```
client
proto udp
remote xxxx 10111
dev tun
sndbuf 393216
rcvbuf 393216
push "sndbuf 393216"
push "rcvbuf 393216"
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
verify-x509-name server_IzA1QdFzHLRFfEoQ name
auth SHA256
auth-nocache
cipher AES-128-CBC
tls-client
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-cipher TLS-ECDHE-ECDSA-WITH-AES-128-GCM-SHA256
setenv opt block-outside-dns # Prevent Windows 10 DNS leak
verb 3
<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIBwTCCAWegAwIBAgIJAPTWURaFGpO8MAoGCCqGSM49BAMCMB4xHDAaBgNVBAMM
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>
<cert>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIBzjCCAXWgAwIBAgIQPwmzIhO7HLkB/Ab7kWjbmjAKBggqhkjOPQQDAjAeMRww
....
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</cert>
<key>
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIGHAgEAMBMGByqGSM49AgEGCCqGSM49AwEHBG0wawIBAQQgIVRqxim4yAGyUect
....
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
</key>
<tls-crypt>
#
# 2048 bit OpenVPN static key
#
-----BEGIN OpenVPN Static key V1-----
72efdfa2e6181538f162076a62dc0330
...
-----END OpenVPN Static key V1-----
</tls-crypt>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I commented out alot of the options in the ovpn file as seen below. I even turned off the tls-ciphers so I didn't have to deal with it in the advanced options in the openvpn setting in DDWRT. I then made sure it works on my desktop client.

Also I did a test by going into the DDWRT router via telnet. And copied the .ovpn file and ran the **openvpn myconf.ovpn** command, which verifies that its working:

[image]

From there I copied the entire .ovpn file into the advanced options > additional config input box.

[image]

It wasn't working at first, but I enabled NAT and it started working!!!!

It should look like this on the status page:

[image]

```
client
proto udp
remote xxx.xxx 10111
dev tun
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
verify-x509-name server_IzA1QdFzHLRFfEoQ name
tun-mtu 1500
auth SHA256
auth-nocache
#cipher AES-128-GCM
#cipher AES-128-CBC
#tls-client
#tls-version-min 1.2
#tls-cipher TLS-ECDHE-ECDSA-WITH-AES-128-GCM-SHA256
#tls-cipher TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-256-CBC-SHA256
#tls-cipher TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-128-CBC-SHA
setenv opt block-outside-dns # Prevent Windows 10 DNS leak
verb 3
<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIBwTCCAWegAwIBAgIJAPTWURaFGpO8MAoGCCqGSM49BAMCMB4xHDAaBgNVBAMM
E......lVFCu0XPwgppkhW2bNblbfbUOBMi
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>
<cert>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIBzjCCAXWgAwIBAgIQPwmzIhO7HLkB/Ab7kWjbmjAKBggqhkjOPQQDAjAeMRww
......iAaZmAMfTcLtsMjw4OO+0J7/m8Aqefo46VPZW4bkabMtA==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</cert>
<key>
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIGHAgEAMBMGByqGSM49AgEGCCqGSM49AwEHBG0wawIBAQQgIVRqxim4yAGyUect
....+Uy+t8Sej1lieG/D3cBVoFkSu2sUvP0FLmFL0eV56VceQKTtk1wtM0N
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
</key>
```